# Making sheet selection using a dialog box and copying into new workbook as values

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write code that allows the user to select a number of sheets in the open workbook and copy them as values into another workbook, which is saved in the same location as the original (with a different name not specified by the user). (I am a relatively new user to VBA, but have had some previous experience with programming before).

I have managed to write code that generates a dialog box populated with check boxes based on the sheets in the work book and create a new file and save it in the appropriate location.

However, I have come across issues at looping through the selected sheets, and copying and pasting them into the new book as values. When I open up the newly created workbook, it is empty. So it seems that the copy/paste has not worked.

The code was originally based off code I found on the net to select any sheets and print them. Any insight to the below code would be greatly appreciated. (I included the extra code that works just in case there is some underlying issue in there that is preventing later code from working).

```
Sub CreateCirculationCopy()

    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim TopPos As Integer
    Dim SheetCount As Integer
    Dim SelectDlg As DialogSheet
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Dim Current As String
    Dim x As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Add a temp dialog sheet
    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set SelectDlg = ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets.Add

    SheetCount = 0

    'Add the checkboxes
    TopPos = 40
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
        'Skip empty and hidden sheets
        If CurrentSheet.Visible Then
            SheetCount = SheetCount + 1
            SelectDlg.CheckBoxes.Add 78, TopPos, 150, 16.5
                SelectDlg.CheckBoxes(SheetCount).Text = _
                CurrentSheet.Name
            TopPos = TopPos + 13
        End If
    Next i

    'Format dialog box
    SelectDlg.Buttons.Left = 240
    With SelectDlg.DialogFrame
        .Height = Application.Max _
            (68, SelectDlg.DialogFrame.Top + TopPos - 34)
        .Width = 230
        .Caption = "Select sheets to copy"
    End With
    SelectDlg.Buttons("Button 2").BringToFront
    SelectDlg.Buttons("Button 3").BringToFront

    'Display the dlg box
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    x = 1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    CurrentSheet.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If SheetCount <> 0 Then
        If SelectDlg.Show Then
            For Each cb In SelectDlg.CheckBoxes
                If cb.Value = x10n Then
                Worksheets(cb.Caption).Activate
                ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
                'ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
                Windows(wb).Activate
                wb.Sheets("Sheet" & x).Activate
                ActiveSheet.Cells("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _
                        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Workbooks(1).Activate
                Worksheets(cb.Caption).Activate
                x = x + 1
                End If
            Next cb
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "All worksheets are empty"
    End If

    Filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Circulation.xlsx"
    wb.SaveAs Filename, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wb.Close

    SelectDlg.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    CurrentSheet.Activate


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DialogSheet` is interesting, but simpler way is create userform with listbox and allow user multiselect `ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti`.

But that is not important :)

Using your, I had a problem with `If cb.Value = x10n Then`, x10n is equal to `Empty`.

Second problem `Windows(wb).Activate`, `wb` it is an object, i use `Windows(wb.Name).Activate`

I had a problem with copying: `ActiveSheet.Cells("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

i change it to `Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

Part of the code with minor modifications:

```
    If SelectDlg.Show Then
        For Each cb In SelectDlg.CheckBoxes
            If cb.Value = 1 Then
            Worksheets(cb.Caption).Activate
            ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
            Windows(wb.Name).Activate
            wb.Sheets("S" & x).Activate
            Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Workbooks(1).Activate
            Worksheets(cb.Caption).Activate
            x = x + 1
            End If
        Next cb
    End If
```

Let me know if it worked

Comment: Hi Dawid, I did try to use a userform, but I found that the dialog box was easier to generate with dynamic information.
Those changes helped, thanks so much. Just have to fiddle with my code a bit more until I get the results that I want. Will post the code when I am done.